# DEAP Genetic Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, genetic, deap

I'm currently using DEAP for the genetic algorithm in Python. I want to create an initial population of individuals that have length `no_sensors`. My problem though is that due to the `random.choice(nodes)` function, some nodes end up being the same and the initial length ends up being less than `no_sensors`. I was wondering if there's a way to fix this:

```
creator.create("FitnessMax", base.Fitness, weights=(2.0, -1.0))
creator.create("Individual", set, fitness=creator.FitnessMax)

toolbox = base.Toolbox()
toolbox.register("attr_item", random.choice, nodes)
toolbox.register("individual", tools.initRepeat, creator.Individual, toolbox.attr_item, n=no_sensors)
toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)
```

Basically, I need a fixed length of unique items from the list `nodes`. I was thinking of using `random.sample(nodes, no_sensors)` but I can't seem to incorporate that into the code without incurring errors

You can check out other example [here](http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorials/basic/part2.html).

Comment: Is `no_sensors` set in advance or is its value possibly different for each individual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thought, I came up with this workaround:

```
creator.create("FitnessMax", base.Fitness, weights=(2.0, -1.0))
creator.create("Individual", list, fitness=creator.FitnessMax)

toolbox = base.Toolbox()
toolbox.register("attr_item", random.sample, nodes, no_sensors)
toolbox.register("individual", tools.initRepeat, creator.Individual, toolbox.attr_item, n=1)
toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)
```

It's a bit ugly though, since everytime you want to access the content of the list `individual` of type `Individual`, you'd have to call `individual[0]`and iterate the content of `individual[0]` which seems pretty redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) and `random.sample`:

```
from functools import partial
import random
no_sensors = 5
mysample = partial(random.sample,k=no_sensors)
toolbox.register("attr_item", mysample, nodes)
```

Comment: The problem though is that if random.choice selects the same value twice, I want it to count as one. Basically, I need a fixed length of unique items from the list: nodes. I was thinking of using random.sample(nodes, no_sensors) but I can't seem to incorporate that into the code without incurring errors.

Comment: a set can't contain lists because they're mutable and therefore not hashable.`set([[1,2,3],3])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: Oh, right! I changed the base of Individual into a list. Even still, a list within a list would seem redundant.